# In Java code i the method i created only put the first duplicate instance to a new array

Tags: java, duplicates

I want to remove the duplicates by putting them in a new array but somehow I only get a first instance and a bunch of zeros.

Here is my code:

```
public class JavaApplication7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] arr = new int[] {1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
       int[] res = removeD(arr);
       for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
       }
    }

    public static int[] removeD(int[] ar) {
        int[] tempa = new int[ar.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] == ar[i+1]) {
                tempa[i] = ar[i];
                return tempa;
            }
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

expected: `1,2`

result: `1,0,0,0,0,0,0....`

Comment: You return immediately after you find the first duplicate.

Comment: Because you return _inside_ the loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you make use of `HashSet`?

```
    final int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (final int i : arr) {
        // makes use of Integer's hashCode() and equals()
        set.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    // primitive int array without zeros
    final int[] newIntArray = new int[set.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    final Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        newIntArray[counter] = iterator.next().intValue();
        counter++;
    }
    for (final int i : newIntArray) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

**Edit**

if you want your array to be ordered

```
    final int[] arr = new int[] { 9, 9, 8, 8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (final int i : arr) {
        // makes use of Integer's hashCode() and equals()
        set.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    // priomitive int array without zeros
    final int[] newIntArray = new int[set.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    // SetUtils.orderedSet(set) requires apache commons collections
    set = SetUtils.orderedSet(set);
    final Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        newIntArray[counter] = iterator.next().intValue();
        counter++;
    }
    for (final int i : newIntArray) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to help you:

1) With this: `for(int i =0; i<ar.length; i++){` - you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are checking `[i+1]`. Hint: it is only the last element that will cause this...

2) Because you're initialising the second `array` with the length of the original `array`, every non-duplicate will be a `0` in it, as each element is initialised with a `0` by default. So perhaps you need to find how many duplicates there are first, before setting the size.

3) As mentioned in the comments, you are returning the `array` once the first duplicate is found, so remove that and just return the `array` at the end of the method.

4) You will also get multiple 2s because when you check `i` with `i+1`, it will find 3 2s and update `tempa` with each of them, so you'll need to consider how to not to include duplicates you've already found - based on your expected result.

These points should help you get the result you desire - if I (or someone else) just handed you the answer, you wouldn't learn as much as if you researched it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int[] tempa = new int[ar.length];
```

That creates a new array with the same size as the incoming one. All slots in that array are initialized with 0s!

When you then put some non-0 values into the first slots, sure, those stick, but so do the 0s in all the later slots that you don't "touch".

Thus: you either have to use a data structure where you can dynamically add new elements (like List/ArrayList), or you have to **first** iterate the input array to determine the exact count of objects you need, to then create an appropriately sized array, to then fill that array.

Answer (score 0):

Return statement

As both commenters said, you return from the method as soon as you find your first duplicate. To resolve that issue, move the return to the end of the method.

Index problems

You will then run into another issue, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because when you are checking your last item (`i = ar.length - 1`) which in your example would be 11 you are then comparing if `ar[11] == ar[12]` but `ar` has size 12 so index 12 is out of the bounds of the array. You could solve that by changing your exit condition of the for loop to `i < ar.length - 1`.

Zeros

The zeros in your current output come from the initialization. You initialize your `tempa` with `int[ar.length]` this means in the memory it will reserve space for 12 ints which are initialized with zero. You will have the same problem after resolving both issues above. Your output would look like this: `1 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`. This is because you use the same index for tempa and ar. You could solve that problem in different ways. Using a List, Filtering the array afterwards, etc. It depends what you want to do exactly.

The code below has the two first issues solved:

```
public class JavaApplication7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        int[] res = removeD(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] removeD(int[] ar) {
        int[] tempa = new int[ar.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length - 1; i++) {
            if (ar[i] == ar[i + 1]) {
                tempa[i] = ar[i];
            }
        }
        return tempa;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a some error mentioned already:

- return exits the method.
- with `arr[i+1] the for condition should be`i+1 < arr.length`.
- the resulting array may be smaller.

So:

```
public static int[] removeD(int[] ar) {
    // Arrays.sort(ar);
    int uniqueCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || ar[i] != ar[i - 1]) {
            ++uniqueCount;
        }
    }

    int[] uniques = new int[uniqueCount];
    int uniqueI = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || ar[i] != ar[i - 1]) {
            uniques[uniqueI] = arr[i];
            ++uniqueI;
        }
    }
    return uniques;
}
```